# Magento Configurable Products / Simple Product not updating

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a catalog of configurable products, each with associated simple products.

e.g.

Dog Food which comes in 2kg, 6kg, 8kg.

The 2kg costs 5.99
The 6kg costs 10.99
The 8kg costs 11.99

The price on the front-end should reflect that of the chosen drop-down options.

My problem. It is not.

My troubleshooting

- I have role back to Default theme to test this and no luck
- I have then looked at using SCP (Simple Configurable Products) to use
  AJAX to update, I have this on a different site and this works fine.
- I have then looked at remove -clone from the priceHtml block as
  discussed on Magento forums

When I add the products to the cart once the drop down is chosen using SCP then the price does update when added to the basket but not on the product view page.

I am now looking at the data and all the data looks correct and the simple products are associated to the configurable.

There are no JS errors in custom theme or default theme.

I am using Magento 1.7

Any ideas?

Comment: did you clear/refresh the cache?

Comment: did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yep. Standard Flushing of Caches on Browser / Server / Varnish have been flushing or now running in Ignito browsing

Comment: would you mind sharing a link to the site in question so that I may get a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: Go to product view. Chose price from dropdown. 

1. http://postimage.org/image/y2h7a97af/

2. http://postimage.org/image/rnn8aibzl/

Add me on Skype: Camfolio
I can send a link if required

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24907/discussion-between-cameron-owen-and-ozzy)